# Integrating exponential function raised to a fractional term

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I'm trying to integrate an exponential term raised to a fractional power with other variables in it.  I'm really rusty and having a hard time trying to figure out where to start.  I'd like to pull out the other terms so I can work on integrating but I'm not sure if or how I can do that with it being part of the exponent.  Below is the what I am trying to integrate.

$$\int_e{e^{\frac{-x^2\beta^2-y^22\alpha^2}{2\alpha^2\beta^2}}dy}$$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you meant with $/2\alpha^2\beta^2$

Comment: Why do you have $\frac{2\alpha^2} {2\alpha^2 \beta^2}$? Strange to have not simplified problem.

Comment: Are any of the other variables functions of $y$ (or vice versa)?

Comment: Also,it is just integral with respect to $y$. So you can pull out $e^{-x^2\beta^2}$. So you are left with $\int_e e^{-y^2 \frac{2\alpha^2}{2\alpha^2\beta^2}}dy$=$\int_e e^{-y^2 \frac{1}{\beta^2}}dy$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indefinite integral would be:
$$\int{e^{\frac{-x^2\beta^2-y^22\alpha^2}{2\alpha^2\beta^2}}dy}$$=$$\int{e^{\frac{-y^22\alpha^2}{2\alpha^2\beta^2}}e^{\frac{-x^2\beta^2}{2\alpha^2\beta^2}}dy}$$=$$\int{e^{\frac{-y^2}{\beta^2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\alpha^2}}dy}$$=$$e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\alpha^2}}\int{e^{\frac{-y^2}{\beta^2}}dy}$$=$$e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\alpha^2}}(\frac{\sqrt\pi\beta\ erf(\frac{y}{\beta})}{2} +C)$$ So just put the limits and you will get the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

we ge this here
$$1/2\,{{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{\frac {{x}^{2}}{{\beta}^{2}}}}}\sqrt {\pi }
\sqrt {2}\alpha\,
{{\rm erf}\left(1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}y}{\alpha}}\right)}
$$

Comment: I think you switched $\alpha$ with $\beta$

Comment: It would be right if 
$$\int_e{e^{\frac{-x^2\alpha^2-y^22\beta^2}{2\alpha^2\beta^2}}dy}$$. You switched the constants.